# Subquery for faster result

Tags: mysql, optimization, subquery, left-join

I have this query which takes me more than 117 seconds on a mysql database.

```
select users.*, users_oauth.* FROM users LEFT JOIN users_oauth ON users.user_id = users_oauth.oauth_user_id WHERE (

             (MATCH (user_email) AGAINST ('sometext')) OR 
             (MATCH (user_firstname) AGAINST ('sometext')) OR 
             (MATCH (user_lastname) AGAINST ('sometext')) )

    ORDER BY user_date_accountcreated DESC LIMIT 1400, 50
```

How can I use a subquery in order to optimize it ?

The 3 fields are fulltext :

```
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `email_fulltext` (`user_email`);
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `firstname_fulltext` (`user_firstname`);
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `lastname_fulltext` (`user_lastname`);
```

There is only one search input in a website to search in different table users fields.

If the limit is for example `LIMIT 0,50`, the query will run in less than 3 seconds but when the LIMIT increase the query becomes very slow.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you run an EXPLAIN with this query and post the results?

Comment: And identify which tables the columns come from.

Comment: Do you have fulltext index created on the fields being searched by match ... against ...?

Comment: A subquery probably will not speed it up but make it slower. Performance questions should include EXPLAIN ANALYZE and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. Slow is a relative term and we need a real value to compare. MySQL Also Please read [How-to-Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Furthermore, why don't you create a single fulltext index on the 3 fields being searched and have a single match ... against ... on the 3 fields instead of the or conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a single FULLTEXT index:

```
FULLTEXT(user_email, user_firstname, user_lastname)
```

And change the 3 matches to just one:

```
MATCH (user_email, user_firstname, user_lastname) AGAINST ('sometext')
```

Here's another issue: `ORDER BY ... DESC LIMIT 1400, 50`.  Read about the evils of [*pagination via OFFSET*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/pagination-optimization/) .  That has a workaround, but I doubt if it would apply to your statement.

Do you really have thousands of users matching the text?  Does someone (other than a search engine robot) really page through 29 pages?  Think about whether it makes sense to really have such a long-winded UI.

And a 3rd issue.  Consider "lazy eval".  That is, find the user ids first, *then* join back to `users` and `users_oauth` to get the rest of the columns.  It would be a single `SELECT` with the `MATCH` in a derived table, then `JOIN` to the two tables.  If the `ORDER BY` an `LIMIT` can be in the derived table, it could be a big win.

Please indicate which table each column belongs to -- my last paragraph is imprecise because of not knowing about the date column.

**Update**

In your second attempt, you added `OR`, which greatly slows things down.  Let's turn that into a `UNION` to try to avoid the new slowdown.  First let's debug the `UNION`:

```
( SELECT *   -- no mention of oauth columns
    FROM users    -- No JOIN
    WHERE users.user_id LIKE ...
    ORDER BY user_id DESC
    LIMIT 0, 50
)
UNION ALL
( SELECT *   -- no mention of oauth columns
    FROM users
    WHERE MATCH ...
    ORDER BY user_id DESC
    LIMIT 0, 50
)
```

Test it by timing each `SELECT` separately.  If one of the is still slow, then let's focus on it.  Then test the `UNION`.  (This is a case where using the mysql commandline tool may be more convenient than PHP.)

By splitting, each `SELECT` can use an optimal index.  The `UNION` has some overhead, but possibly less than the inefficiency of `OR`.

Now let's fold in users_oauth.

First, you seem to be missing a very important `INDEX(oauth_user_id)`.  Add that!

Now let's put them together.

```
SELECT u.*
    FROM ( .... the entire union query ... ) AS u
    LEFT JOIN users_oauth ON users.user_id = users_oauth.oauth_user_id
    ORDER BY user_id DESC   -- yes, repeat
    LIMIT 0, 50             -- yes, repeat
```

Comment: Thanks Rick, I added a reply with tables columns

Comment: How did you guess ? Indeed I forgot the `INDEX(oauth_user_id)` and now this request takes me 0.6615 seconds :)
Thanks you Rick, now I understand the UNION ALL and how to manage with. :)

Comment: Although `DESCRIBE` is not as descriptive as `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, it hinted that the index was probably missing.  About the only reason for a `JOIN` taking a lot of extra time is a missing (or inadequate) index.

Answer (score 0):

Yes @Rick

I changed the index fulltext to:

```
ALTER TABLE `users`
   ADD FULLTEXT KEY `fulltext_adminsearch` (`user_email`,`user_firstname`,`user_lastname`);
```

And now there is some php conditions, $_POST['search'] can be empty:

```
if(!isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $searchId = '%' ;
} else {
    $searchId = $_POST['search'] ;
}
$searchMatch = '+'.str_replace(' ', ' +', $_POST['search']);
$sqlSearch = $dataBase->prepare(
      'SELECT users.*, users_oauth.*
           FROM users
           LEFT JOIN users_oauth ON users.user_id = users_oauth.oauth_user_id 
           WHERE (    users.user_id LIKE :id OR 
                     (MATCH (user_email, user_firstname, user_lastname)
                            AGAINST (:match IN BOOLEAN MODE)) ) 
           ORDER BY user_id DESC LIMIT 0,50') ;

$sqlSearch->execute(array('id'    => $searchId,
                          'match' => $searchMatch )) ;
```

The users_oauth table has a column with user_id:

Table users:

```
    +--------------------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field                    | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +--------------------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | user_id                  | int(8) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | user_activation_key      | varchar(40)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | user_email               | varchar(40)     | NO   | UNI |         |                |
    | user_login               | varchar(30)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | user_password            | varchar(40)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | user_firstname           | varchar(30)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | user_lastname            | varchar(50)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | user_lang                | varchar(2)      | NO   |     | en      
    +--------------------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Table users_oauth:

```
+----------------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| oauth_id             | int(8) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| oauth_user_id        | int(8) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| oauth_google_id      | varchar(30)     | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| oauth_facebook_id    | varchar(30)     | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| oauth_windowslive_id | varchar(30)     | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
+----------------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The Left Join is long, the request takes 3 seconds with, 0,0158 seconds wihtout.

It would be more rapid to make a sql request for each 50 rows.

Would it be more rapid with a subquery ? How to make it with a subquery ?

Thanks